# Python - Split a column into multiple columns no delimiter (column YYYYMM to coulmns YYYY and MM)

Tags: python, dataframe

How can i split column YYYYMM into columns YYYY and MM?

```
import pandas as pd 
sample_data=pd.DataFrame(['201801','201702','201803','201904'])
sample_data.columns=['YYYYMM']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the you know for sure the data would always be that format you could try

```
# Split data and store in separate columns
sample_data['YYYY'] = sample_data[0].str[:4]
sample_data['MM'] = sample_data[0].str[4:]


    0       YYYY    MM
0   201801  2018    01
1   201702  2017    02
2   201803  2018    03
3   201904  2019    04
```

Answer (score 0):

> this is also an option

```
sample_data=pd.DataFrame(['201801','201702','201803','201904'])

for i in sample_data:
    sample_data = str(i[0:4] + "/" + i[4:6])
    print(sample_data)
```

> output: 2018/01,2017/02, 2018/03, 2019/04